# How to find captive portal page at BOSwifi (Logan Airport wifi)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, public-wifi

At Logan Airport in Boston USA, there's a public network called BOSwifi. On my Macbook Air laptop, it used to work, but now after the wifi connects, I can't go to any web pages - I believe it's because the captive splash page is waiting for me to click "Accept" but no browser brings it up anymore. How do I force it to show me the captive page? I don't see it in any browsers' history, and restarting, or forgetting the wifi network doesn't work. Does anyone know the splash page for BOSwifi or how to find it?  My iPhone can get on, but I can't get Safari to tell me what the splash page URL was.

Answer (score 0):

Omg I’ve been dealing with this. Tried everything and then realized in the massport screen that pops up where there is no ACCEPT checkbox, YOU SIMPLY HAVE TO SCROLL DOWN WITH YOUR ARROWS EVEN THOUGH THERE IS NO VISIBLE CURSOR.
This was a serious DOH! Moment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1201808)

Answer (score -1):

Edit: after looking into this further with the help of the user Spiff, the solution below could lead to security issues should a potentially malicious admin have whitelisted the site captive.apple.com in order to set tracking cookies.
A better solution would be to visit some other insecure HTTP page to attempt the redirection.

<strike>To force redirection to a captive portal - visit [captive.apple.com](https://captive.apple.com)

If you are connected successfully - you will see "Success".

Otherwise, it should load the captive portal page.</strike>

Comment: I tried it, and it just sat there "connecting..." and couldn't get to it. So maybe it's having a problem prior to the captive page, but the wifi icon is indicating all connected (full bars) and my iPhone gets on with no problem. Any idea where it could be failing, if it can't get to captive.apple.com?

Comment: This is bad advice for Apple product users. captive.apple.com is what Apple's captive portal detector already uses, so if they didn't already see the captive portal handler window, it means the network they're on has whitelisted captive.apple.com for likely-nefarious reasons. It would be better to advise Apple users to try making some other insecure HTTP connection.

Comment: @Spiff from my experience, it has been a good way to force the page to load, but your comment suggests otherwise. Can you elaborate on what an attacker could gain from whitelisting this page? Just out of interest

Comment: @Milo It forces you to use a real browser, so it allows the captive portal Wi-Fi network operator to set tracking cookies on your real browser. It's an anti-privacy move.

Comment: @Spiff thanks for the info, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MikeLevin try forgetting the WiFi network, and renewing IP, see instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1545/mac)

Comment: I tried forgetting the WiFi network and renewing DHCP but it didn't help. I've more recently been told that the right page is splash.massport.com - I'll try it out in 10 days to see if it works. But maybe this will help someone meanwhile.

Comment: @MikeLevin Thanks for the update - have you had a chance to try?